# use httpcontext in crm 2011 plugin using c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am using the following httpcontext for making the word file of description of email entity. It works perfectly but disable the form after execution of the doc file.

```
private void exporToWord(string subject, string html)
        {

            string strFileName = subject + ".doc";

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
            StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
            strHTMLContent.Append(html);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

        }//End of exporToWord()
```

Subject is the subject of the email activity and the html is the description of the activity.

Please I want to seek your kind help in this regards.

Thank You.

Comment: @Moderators Duplicated question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880222/use-httpcontext-in-crm-2011-plugin-using-c-sharp

Comment: I am following this for CRM 2011 Plugin but the problem still the same http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/590d4fe2-4c70-4971-99a4-45c22534215b/download-file-problem-in-user-control-loader-web-part

Comment: This doesn't mean that you need to create new thread every day with the same question.

Comment: You need to either accept an answer, post your answer, or remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the HttpContext from CRM Plugin is not supported functionality.

A CRM Plugin always fires during an Event. If it is a synchronous plugin the end of that event will be a response to the calling client. If you write out the HttpContext inside the plugin you are going to break the event's pipeline and cause the transaction to be incomplete.